# Countly iOS SDK fails request

Tags: ios, countly-analytics

I have added Count.ly iOS SDK to project, in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I have added Count.ly initialisation as

```
        let config: CountlyConfig = CountlyConfig()
        config.appKey = "MY_APP_KEY"
        config.host = "https://try.count.ly/"
        config.enableDebug = true
        config.deviceID = CLYIDFV
        config.updateSessionPeriod = 300
        //You can specify optional features you want here
        config.features = [CLYCrashReporting, CLYAutoViewTracking]

        Countly.sharedInstance().start(with: config)
```

But in console it is giving error

> [Countly] Request <0x170003290> failed!

And it is not showing anything on dashboard. My Account is on trial version enterprise edition. Do I have to do any other configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you do not add extra `/` at the end of host.

```
config.host = "https://try.count.ly/"
```

should be

```
config.host = "https://try.count.ly"
```

Disclaimer: I'm the SDK Developer

(EDIT: incorrect host configurations like this one is now handled automatically on v17.05+)

Comment: This fixed the issue. But this code was generated by their documentation, it is bug from their side.

Comment: Can you give a link to incorrect documentation. I'ill make sure it is fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, http://code.count.ly/integration-ios.html?server=MY_HOST/&app_key=MY_APP_KEY

Comment: Can't reproduce using this link, because there is an extra slash after `MY_HOST`.

Comment: I have changed my host and app key in url which I provided you.  The auto generated code can be found at Dashboard->Management->Application , in "Need some help with SDK integration?"  section click on ios, on new page click "Generate"

Comment: Thank you. I will check. `UPDATE:` I checked and confirmed now. I will inform the team. Thank you very much again.

Comment: @erkanyildiz Countly working fine on development but when I upload it to TestFlight then no log generated. Already added config.pushTestMode = .testFlightOrAdHoc